# get the string resources dynamic for a question app

Tags: android

I am developing a question app. I got some questions in my string resource file. Each time a user touches the textview it changes the question. 
I have all the questions stored in an array, but I don't think this is very efficient.

```
            max_Fragen = FragenBeginner.length - 1;
            min_Fragen = 0;
            //Fragen Nummer
            randomFrage = rand.nextInt((max_Fragen - min_Fragen) + 1) + min_Fragen;                
            fragekatalog = getResources().getString(R.string.fragen_FragenBeginner_ + randomFrage);              
            frage.setText(fragekatalog);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i cant get my string ressource, because the code doesn't recognize "fragen_FragenBeginner_ + randomFrage" as "fragen_FragenBeginner_15"  for example

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
public static int getStringIdentifier(Context context, String name) {
    return context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "string", context.getPackageName());
}
```

to use a variable as a string identifier.